# SQL logic error or missing database in Blackberry programming

Tags: java, sqlite, blackberry

I am trying to insert data into a SQLite database from a blackberry. When I call the screen I also call a method to create the database:

```
boolean sdCardPresent = false;

public static Database sqliteDB;

URI uri;
public  void createdatabase()
{

    try{
        Enumeration e = FileSystemRegistry.listRoots();
        root = (String)e.nextElement();
        Dialog.inform(root);
        if(root.equalsIgnoreCase("sdcard/"))
        {
        sdCardPresent = true;
        }
    if(!sdCardPresent)
        {
            Dialog.inform("O seu dispositivo nao suporta este compartimento sem cartao de memoria, verifique se existe um SD card no seu dispositivo.");
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new Tab_Main());

        }else{
         uri = URI.create(
            "file:///SDCard/Databases/MBA.db");
        sqliteDB = DatabaseFactory.openOrCreate(uri);
        sqliteDB = DatabaseFactory.open(uri);
        Statement st = sqliteDB.createStatement("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS atms;CREATE  TABLE atms " +
                "( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ," +
                "  localizacao TEXT, " +
                "  mapa TEXT ," +
                "  foto1 TEXT ," +
                "  foto2 TEXT," +
                "  zona TEXT);" +
                "" +
                "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS balcoes;CREATE  TABLE balcoes " +
                "(  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ," +
                "  localizacao TEXT, " +
                "  mapa TEXT ," +
                "  foto1 TEXT ," +
                "  foto2 TEXT," +
                "  zona TEXT);" +
                "" +
                "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contactos;CREATE  TABLE contactos " +
                "( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ," +
                "  nome TEXT, " +
                "  numero_conta INTEGER);") ;
           st.prepare();
           st.execute();
           st.close();
           sqliteDB.close();
        Dialog.inform("Status: Database was successfully created.");
        //}
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        Dialog.inform("\n "+e);
        //UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(Screen);
    }

}
```

After that I use some Editfields and other components to get the values. I call the method to insert the parameters and send the query:

> ```
>   public  void insert_update(String query) {
>     try {
> ```

```
                sqliteDB = DatabaseFactory.openOrCreate(uri);
        Statement st = sqliteDB.createStatement(query);                 
        //Statement statement = _db.createStatement(query); 
        st.prepare();                                          
        st.execute();  
        st.close();
        Dialog.inform("Adicionado com sucesso!!!");
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) {         
        Dialog.inform(e+"");
    }
}
```

For example when I call it with the `query = "insert into contactos values (null,"a","1");` I get an exception. SQL logic error or missing database.

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping the quotes around the third column value.

```
INSERT INTO contactos VALUES (null,"a", 1);
```

It's defined as an INTEGER.

```
numero_conta INTEGER
```

***EDIT*** :

```
System.out.println(uri); // check if null, or different
if (uri == null) {
    uri = URI.create(
       "file:///SDCard/Databases/MBA.db");
}
sqliteDB = DatabaseFactory.openOrCreate(uri);
sqliteDB = DatabaseFactory.open(uri); // open again

Statement st = sqliteDB.createStatement(query);
```

Comment: No, it not works i try to, i try INSERT INTO contactos VALUES (null,'a', 1); and i obtain the same result... help

Comment: Could you please update the full exception stack trace in your question?

Comment: net.rim.device.api.database.DatabaseException: Insert into contactos values (null,'a',1):SQL logic error or missing database

Comment: The uri value on System.out.println "file:///SDCard/Databases/MBA.db", but an new exception has catched net.rim.device.api.database.DatabaseIOException: File System Error(12).